# squaring a summation syntax

Tags: summation

In the following summation:

${\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(x_{i}-\bar{x}\right)^{2}}$

Do I first add all the $x_i - \bar{x}$  then I square the sum?

Or do I square each $x_i - \bar{x}$ as I add them up?

Sorry for the silly question -- but the syntax is confusing me if the square is included in every iteration of the sum or just at the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square each $x_i-\bar x$ as you add them up.

The summand is $(x_i-\bar x)^2$.

For the first case, the sum would look like this:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-\bar{x})\right)^{2}$$

(and will equal to zero:)

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_{i}-\bar{x})\right)^{2} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\bar{x}\right)^{2} = \left(N\bar x-N\bar x\right)^{2}=0$$

Comment: Thanks so much @player3236  Just a quick question on what you mean that "will equal zero"?

Comment: The sum of $N$ copies of the mean will equal the sum of all $N$ of the $x_i$.

Comment: Thanks so much. Super helpful